# Proving that the set of all finite subsets of a countable set is coutable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

> Proposition: Let $S$ be a countable set. Then the set of all finite subsets of $S$ is also countable.

---

**My approach:**

If $S$ is countable that means that $S$ is finite or that $S \sim\mathbb{N}$.

If $S$ is finite then the number of finite subsets of $S$ is also finite, so in this case it's easy to show that this is countable as well.

*In the case that $S$ is countably infinite:*

Let $A_k=\{A \subset S:\text{card} (A)=k\}$. $A_k$ is countable because it is the union of various countable sets $A \subset S$

The set of all finite subsets of $S$ will be equal to $\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. Because every $A_i$ is countable, then this union is also countable.

My question is: Can I do this union? Because $A_\infty$ means the set is the set of all infinite subsets of $S$, and I'm making an union from $i=1$ to $\infty$. So is this proof right?

Comment: Yes , the proof is valid since the union of countable many countable sets is countable.

Comment: You need to justify why $A_k$ is countable....how do you know that there are only countably many subsets in the "union" you speak of. Hint: Find an injection from $A_k$ to $S^k$ (Cartesian product of $S$ $k$ times).

Comment: In the book I'm following they proved the following as a lemma: If $S_1,...,S_n,...$ is a countably infinite family of countable sets, then $\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i$ is countably infinite set. That does prove that $A_k$ is countable because $A_k$ is the union of countable sets right? @halrankard

Comment: $A_k$ is defined as a *set of subsets* of $S$, but then you say "$A_k$ is a union of (countable) sets $A\subset S$". But a union of subsets of $S$ is again a subset of $S$, not a *set of subsets* of $S$. So saying these two things are equal doesn't add up. OTOH your lemma *does* apply at the later step where you conclude that the set (call it $A_*$) of all finite subsets of $S$ is countable since it is a union of the $A_{k}$'s. Everything lines up: $A_*$ is a *set of subsets of $S$* and so are the $A_{k}$'s. But you still need a complete justification for why each $A_{k}$ is countable.

Comment: P.S. This is why I put union in quotation marks in my first comment. I had a feeling that there might be this problem in the reasoning but I wasn't sure until your question about the lemma. Sometimes this is why people might use $A, B, C$ for subsets and then something like $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\ldots$ for *sets of subsets*. This can help one to remember what level things live at.

Comment: P.P.S. About your last question. Given a sequence of $A_{i}$'s defined for $i$ a natural number, the notation $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ is generally understood to mean the union over natural numbers $i=1,2,\ldots$. So as long as you're clear that $A_{i}$ is defined for $i$ finite there should be no problem. But this exposes a minor issue: the emptyset $\emptyset$ is a finite subset of $S$ which is not in the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$. In other words you need an $A_{0}$ to go with the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with that union. However, it is wrong to assert that $A_k$ is countable “because it is the union of various countable sets”. An arbitray union of countable sets doesn't have to be countable. You have to justify that you have a *countable* union of countable sets here.