# Prove that $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{N})$ is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{N})$ denote the set of two-element subsets of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{N})$ is countably infinite. How can I do that?

Comment: It is well-known that $\Bbb{N}^2$ is countably infinite. There is a pretty obvious injection of your set into $\Bbb{N}^2$.

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: It's not that hard to come up with an explicit bijection $f:  \Bbb N \to \mathcal P_2(\Bbb N)$.  Drawing a picture should help you see it.

Comment: @C-RAM  
I identified these sets with pairs (n, m) \in \mathbb{N}^2, where n>m. I drew it in a coordinate system for better intuition, and it came out like an infinite triangle. All in all, I need some formal proof, someone said I can use Cantor Berstein's theorem but I have no idea how.

Comment: @RobertShore So it's enough to simply define, for example,  $f:N \rightarrow P_2(N)$,
$f(n) = \{n, n+1\}$ function and prove that it's a bijection, right?

Comment: That won't be a bijection, because there are lots of $2$-element subsets (such as $\{34, 971 \}$) that aren't of the form $\{n, n+1 \}$.  You need a function that picks up all such subsets.

Comment: @RobertShore woah that's right but I've been thinking for a long time and still haven't come up with any bijection, can you give me a hint?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832838/is-the-set-of-all-two-element-subsets-of-z-countable-or-uncountable (but that question has no nondeleted answer). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741172/proving-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-a-countable-set-is-coutable solves a question which includes the question posed here.

Comment: @gENz1337 That's an honest attempt. You should add that attempt to your question.

Comment: Sure.  Start with all $2$-element subsets that have $1$ as their largest element.  Then move on to all $2$-element subsets that have $2$ as their largest element.  Lather, rinse, repeat.  it's a little tedious, but you can create an explicit formula that enumerates the sets in that order.

Comment: Have you had a look at the (second) link I posted? or at the answer @Nuke posted?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a diagonal argument. First, consider all tuples $(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ and order them by $n$ in columns and $m$ in the rows, which leads to:
$$\begin{array}{cc}
(1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) &\cdots\\
(2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) & \cdots\\
(3,1) & (3,2) & (3,3) & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
$$
So, by using a diagonal argument (similar to proving that the $|\mathbb{Q}|$ is countably infinite), you can prove that there are countably infinitely many of these vectors.

Now, the set you are actually looking at consists of two-element subsets $\{n,m\}$, i.e. $\{n,m\} = \{m,n\}$ (as opposed to $(n,m)\neq (m,n)$) $-$ so it is can be identified with an infinite subset of the former one which then also has to be countably infinite.

(Or, of course, alternatively, you could just look at the upper triangle of the above enumeration scheme $-$ whatever you find easier to understand.)